# Destroying TADODataset created in runtime

Tags: delphi, function, destroy, tadodataset

I have a function that returns a TADODataset object:

// inside DataModule:

```
function TDM.GetWorkstationsList: TADODataset;
var
  DS: TADODataSet;
begin
  DS := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
  DS.Connection := MyConnection;  // MyConnection is TADOConnection
  DS.CommandType := cmdText;
  DS.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM Workstation';
  DS.Active := True;
  Result := DS;
end;
```

This is how I plan to use it:

```
// inside main form: 

tvWorkstation.DataController.DataSource.DataSet := DM.GetWorkstationsList; // tvWorkstation is TcxGridDBTableView
```

As far as I know, if I create an object manually in runtime, I must destroy it manually at some moment to avoid memory leaks. How and when should I destroy my created dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make use of Delphi's ownership mechanism. You can pass in an owner (of type `TComponent`) in the constructor and then your data set will be destroyed whenever the owner is destroyed. In your case, just pass the form as the owner.

```
function TDM.CreateWorkstationsList(Owner: TComponent): TADODataSet;
begin
DS := TADODataSet.Create (Owner);
...
end;

DataSource.DataSet := DM.CreateWorkstationsList (Self);
```

You could also destroy the data set manually, for example in the form's `OnDestroy` event.